# Calculating a VWAP using close prices snapshot

Tags: finance-mathematics, statistical-finance

I was wondering, is it possible to calculate a daily VWAP (Volume weighted Average Price) from the close snap shot (close price, high, low open and total volume traded over the day)?

If so is there a formula?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need the volume at each traded price level.